# How to execute a list of EXEC sp_* commands and continue on any errors

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, is it possible to execute a list of `EXEC` commands and just let it continue on any errors?

I know this seems counter intuitive. But we use a generated script for adding the meta-data of the columns as extended properties, this metadata is used in the application forms.

See example below, in practice it's hundreds of lines like this.

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'VarLabel', 'Patient ID', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', ID
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'VarLabel', 'Patient name', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', PATNAME
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'VarLabel', 'Sex', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', SEX
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'ValLabel001', '1 = Male', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', SEX
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'ValLabel002', '2 = Female', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', SEX
-- etc. hundreds of lines
```

When adding new columns I used to just run this entire script, which would give many `property already exists` errors, but the extended properties for the new columns would still be added. Whereas now, if the extended property of the first line already exists, then it just gives one single error and stops immediately on that line and doesn't continue.

This was very practical to just run it all, compared to now I have to hand-pick only the meta-data for the new columns out of this large script and run only those lines, especially because there are lots of columns.

I know I could textedit it and add a `GO` after line, then it does work, so like this:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'VarLabel', 'Patient ID', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', ID
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'VarLabel', 'Patient name', N'USER', DBO, N'VIEW', VW_DEMO, N'COLUMN', PATNAME
GO
```

But that requires some extra steps and I'm positive I used to be able to run it as-is. I work with SQL Management Studio v17.5, is this maybe a feature that was dropped after v16 or something? I've looked at Tools > Options menu, and editor settings but I couldn't find any setting for this.

Comment: USE `TRY...CATCH` and *don't* `THROW` the error? Use`SET XACT_ABORT OFF;`?

Answer (score 0):

What [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484879/larnu) has said. Just wrap each statement in a `TRY...CATCH` block.

I can't remember if you can leave `CATCH` block empty, if you cannot - perhaps just add a `PRINT` command, write to logs that execution has failed.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the same solution as adding `GO` after each line. My question is; it used to be possible but now not anymore, is there a reason or is is there a setting or command to enable it again?

Comment: I see are you 100% sure you were able to run it as is?

Comment: Yes 100%, it was part of my workflow because it was such a fast way to do it.